# "Provide us with X" or "provide us X"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, ditransitivity

Does *provide* need the preposition *with,* or is it truly ditransitive?

> - Kindly provide us **with** your best quotation
>     Kindly provide us your best quotation.
> - He provided directions.
>     He provided us directions.
>     He provided us with directions.

Comment: Comparing with the acceptability of all of _She taught maths / She taught us /  She taught us maths_, one might well suppose so. However, _He provided us directions / sandwiches_ sounds totally unidiomatic to my ears. Verb argumentation is often unpredictable and hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 5):

**provide** (**[Collins COBUILD English Usage)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/provide)**

- **'provide with'***

  > To provide something that someone needs or wants means to give it to
  >   them or make it available to them. You say that you **provide someone
  >   with** something.

> *They **provided him with** money to buy new clothes.*
>
> *We can **provide you with** information that may help you to find a job.*
>
> **Be Careful!** You must use **with** in sentences like these. Don't say, for example, *'They provided him money to buy new clothes'.*

- ***'provide for'***

  > You can also say that you provide something for someone.

> *The animals **provide food for** their young.*
>
> *The hospital **provides care for** thousands of sick children.*
>
> **Be Careful!** Don't use any preposition except **for** in sentences like these. Don't say, for example *'The animals provide food to their
>   young'.*
>
> If you ***provide for someone***, you regularly give them the things
>   they need, such as money, food, or clothing.
>
> *Parents are expected to **provide for** their children.*
>
> *If he dies, will the family be **provided for**?*
>
> **Be Careful!** You must use **for** in sentences like these. Don't say, for example, *'Parents are expected to provide their children'.*

Comment: It's interesting that "Parents are expected to provide their children" is OK (it does actually mean something, although not the same thing as *provide for their children*) but "They provided him money" is not OK. The answer doesn't provide a rationale for that, although it hints at it.

Comment: The answer may not provide a rationale, but it does provide a reliable authority forbidding a ditransitive usage. Good sleuthing.